# Validation on Booking Object

Tags: validation-rule

I am not able to use correctly validation rule please help me....

1. When Status is Not-Confirmed:
                               Room No. shouldn't be selected otherwise room no is must.
                               And Check In and Check out time should be empty.
2. If Status is Confirmed
       Room No is must And
       Check In Time and Check Out Time must be empty.
3. If Status is Check In
       Room No is must and
       Check In Time can't be empty. And
       Check out time must be empty.
4. If status is Check Out
       Room No is must and
       Check In and Check Out Time can't be empty.
5. And Check Out time must be greater than check in time.

**API Names**

Check In Time

```
Check_In_Time__c
```

Date/Time Check Out Time

```
Check_Out_Time__c
```

Date/Time Room No `Room_No__c`  Number(15, 0)

Status  `Status__c` Picklist

```
Booking__c
```

**Validation Rule**

```
IF(ISPICKVAL( Status__c ,"Not Confirmed"), ISNULL( Room_No__c),False)
```

Comment: Can you please provide the API names for the object and the fields? Also, what have you tried so far? Show us your attempt/s

Comment: Check In Time  
 Check_In_Time__c Date/Time 
Check Out Time  
 Check_Out_Time__c Date/Time 
Room No  
 Room_No__c Number(15, 0) 
Status  
 Status__c Picklist

Comment: API Name Booking__c                                                                                Check In Time,
Check_In_Time__c (Date/Time ) ,                                                               Check Out Time,                                                                               Check_Out_Time__c(Date/Time )
Room No
Room_No__c (Number(15, 0) )
Status
Status__c (Picklist)

Comment: People on here are happy to help when you come up against an issue, but this looks like you're just trying to get everyone to do your job for you.  You really need to show us what you've tried and what part of it isn't working.  For validation rules, a screenshot of the validation rule will help as well as the actual validation rule.

Comment: Is it possible to do..

Comment: Please do it one by one....                                                                                             When Status is Not-Confirmed: Room No. shouldn't be selected otherwise room no is must. And Check In and Check out time should be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with five (5) VRs

The first VR is

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(Status__c,'Not Confirmed'), 
    OR(NOT(ISBLANK(Room_no__c)),        /* w/ room# */
       NOT(ISBLANK(Check_in_time__c)),  /* or w/ checkin date */
       NOT(ISBLANK(Check_out_time__c()  /* or w/ checkout date
      )
   )

Error Message: "Unconfirmed reservations can't have room#, checkin or check out date"
```

The rest I leave as an exercise to you

A suggestion: complex VRs should be written with each condition on a separate line, adequately commented, with proper indenting to make it easy to debug and/or enhance over time